# Getting Last Type of Curried Function

Tags: scala, currying

Given a `val` that consists of the following (what I believe is a) `type constructor with a curried function argument`, `F[A => B => C]`...

```
val x: F[A => B => C] = foo() // foo does not matter
```

Is it possible for me to get `F[C]` from `x`?

`val y: F[C] = x...`

**EDIT** 
For context,  I'm trying to implement the `map3` function from Functional Programming in Scala.

Comment: `F` in this case is a functor? Does it have an apply? The reason I'm asking is that we'll need some way of accessing the contained function.

Comment: Yes `F` is an Applicative Functor (not ssure if different). Here's the apply - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/8277018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get `F[C]` from `F[A => B => C]` is if you can apply an `A` and a `B` to it. That is, you'll need to evaluate the contained function. Use the `apply` twice, once to get an `B => C` and then once again to get `C`.

```
def eval(myApp: F[A => B => C])(value: F[A]): F[B => C]
def evalAgain(myApp: F[B => C])(value: F[B]): F[C]
```

but if you just want to be able to get `F[C]` directly from the function itself without evaluation, you're SOL.

**Edit**:

I believe it would look like this.

```
def eval(myApp: F[A => B => C])(value: F[A], next: F[B])(implicit ap: Applicative[F[_]]) = ap(ap(myApp, value), next)
```

Comment: Thanks,  wheaties. Could you please provide a REPL example for my own learning? (Maybe I'm off the mark for this map3 function. )

Comment: Thanks a lot, @wheaties. I didn't use the `implicit`, but my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962850/must-follow-curried-method) is very similar to yours.